# Tomcat session replication. FarmWarDeployer or not?

Tags: tomcat, session-replication

I'm setting up clustered tomcat environment with session replication. I need to figure out how to deploy updates without any downtime, and without users loosing session.

I've been looking into using the built in deploy mechanism (FarmWarDeployer), but I haven't found good documentation on how this work.

I'm thinking about using a script which deploys on one tomcat, then waits/sleeps for a time, then deploys on the next tomcat. But I have to be sure that each session has been replicated to the newly started tomcat.

Lets say we have 500 active session on a running tomcat, then restarts another tomcat in the cluster, is it a time consuming job to replicate these sessions to the newly started tomcat?

Regarding the FarmWarDeployer. Will it deploy updates on one Tomcat at a time?